# Run java -jar myjar.jar as new thread in java

Tags: java, processbuilder, runtime.exec

Is any way to run new thread(JVM) in current java program?

Let's say I have program mainApp.jar what will start:
"java -jar C:/myjar/app1.jar -param 001"
"java -jar C:/myjar/app2.jar -param 001"
"java -jar C:/myjar/app3.jar -param 001"

But I need app1, app2, app3 in new thread(new JVM).

For now I try Runtime.getRuntime().exec and ProcessBuilder

1st method: ProcessBuilder

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("java", "-jar" "C:/myjar/app1.jar -p 001");
                                pb.inheritIO();
                                pb.redirectError();
                                Process ps = pb.start();
```

2nd method: Runtime

```
                            Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java -jar app1.jar -i 100",null,new File("C:/myjar"));
                            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
                            String line = null;
                            while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                                    LOG.info("LOG : " + line);
                            }
```

Both methods works, but they start my app1.jar in the same thread. Is any way to start app1.jar, app2.jar as new JVM?

System: Windows Server 2012,
IntelliJ Idea 15.0.4

Comment: What do you mean "they start in the same Thread"? They start in a new JVM, thus cannot run on the same Java Thread. However, they can run on the same CPU thread, you have no control over that.

Comment: Thank you for an answer. I don't want and don't need to control them. When I start on method1 and method2 I have all programs in "one java window". Is any way to start app1, app2... in "new java window" ?

Comment: What you are saying is not true. You might see the console text from the 2nd process in the 1st window, but that is because you redirect its output or read from it. However, the code you show here will spawn a new JVM in a different process.